# Applet shown nothing at all

Tags: java, swing, applet

When I ran the Java code, I found that the Applet shows nothing at all. But the Applet window indicated to me that "Applet Started"

HelloWorld.java, the main program.

```
import javax.swing.*;

    public class HelloWorld extends JApplet{
        public static void main(String[] args){

            TheWindow w = new TheWindow();
            w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            w.setSize(230, 280);
            w.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

DrawOval.java, which is to draw the circle

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawOval extends JPanel{

    private int d = 10;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(10, 10, d, d);
    }

    public void setD(int newD){
        d = (newD >=0 ? newD : 10);
        repaint();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

}
```

TheWindow.java, which is to define the slider's attributes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class TheWindow extends JFrame{

    private JSlider slider;
    private DrawOval myPanel;

    public TheWindow(){
        super("title");
        myPanel = new DrawOval();
        myPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 200, 10);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);

        slider.addChangeListener(
                new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        myPanel.setD(slider.getValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Anyone just give me a hint, it will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Well since, applets don't have a `main` method, if you load it via the browser or applet viewer, the `main` method will never be called.  Applets really shouldn't be creating standalone windows anyway...

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thompson how awesome and cool you are!!!! I really love your style!! I learned Applet because in recent day I have learned Java tutorial by thenewboston in YouTube. That's why I learn Applet.

Comment: *"That's why I learn Applet."* Skip the part on applets.  If that leaves too little left to teach, find another tutorial.  I can remember hearing of the tutorials at The 'New' Boston years ago (before applets became non-viable), and doubt they've changed or been updated since then.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks Thompson :-)